# the specified field 'Match ID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your sql statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to give the number of matches that a player did not play but listed in the team. If he hasnt played his Minutes per game will be zero which i have implemented. PLease PLease Help!!!

```
SELECT tblGameResults.MatchID, Player_ID_Number, Minutes_Per_Game
FROM 
  tblGameResults 
INNER JOIN 
  tblPlayerStatistics ON tblGameResults.MatchID = tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID
WHERE Minutes_Per_Game = 0
GROUP BY 
  tblGameResults.MatchID
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your query looks conceptually like it would work, here are a few pointers (I am making some guesses on the tables where Minutes_Per_Game and Player_ID_Number come from):

Give aliases to all of your table names

```
SELECT game.MatchID, stats.Player_ID_Number, stats.Minutes_Per_Game
FROM 
  tblGameResults as game
INNER JOIN 
  tblPlayerStatistics as stats ON game.MatchID = stats.MatchID
WHERE stats.Minutes_Per_Game = 0
GROUP BY 
  game.MatchID
```

This should help you identify where your problems are, or it will help the database know where to pull columns from. Additionally, you are selecting three columns. You should probably group by all of them unless you want to do some aggregate functions on the last two in your select statement.

Comment: the aggregate error has come up unfortunatley and I have tried to edit that but it hasn't worked. the minutes per game and player id are coming from player statistics table and the match id from the game results table. Is there anything else possible that i can try with that additional information?? thanks again